# Change Tomcat port to 80 with Apache?

Tags: tomcat

I have a VPS that had Apache. Later Tomcat was installed with the cPanel EasyApache thing. JSPs will work as Mysite.com/file.jsp or mysite.com:8080/file.jsp. However, JForum uses web.XML to map some servlets to URLs. Without the port 8080 in the URL, I get file not found. Is there any way to get the servlets to map on port 80 like the JSPs without killing Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mod_proxy for passing the data over to tomcat.

you could use something in the lines of:

```
ProxyPass /myservlet http://localhost:8080/myservlet
ProxyPassReverse /myservlet http://localhost:8080/myservlet
```

That will proxy the data to the tomcat instance and rewrite replies so that they match the given path. I would recommend using something like nginx for plain proxying, but if you already need apache for something, it can be done with it too.

Comment: Why do JSPs work without having to be proxied?

Comment: Without knowing the full details of your configuration I'm going to assume you use similar configuration as this one:

"JkMount /*.jsp ajp13"

The *.jsp rule would explain why you can only access jsp pages.

If you wish to use mod_jk, you need to mount the poper patterns that you wish to access through apache. The benefit of using ProxyPass is that you can rewrite locations if you need to and when using mod_jk you get to skip a few extra requests on the server side.

Comment: I did, in fact, have the JkMount thing. I added the directory, and now everything is working on port 80.